# How to Implement FloodFill Algorithm in iphone

Tags: iphone, flood-fill

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FloodFill in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862707/floodfill-in-iphone)

I want to implement floodfill algorithm in iphone.What are the methods are used to implement the floodfill algorithm in iphone.Please any one guide me in this regard.

If i want to include any of the frameworks means please explain about that framework.

Thanks & Regards

Renuga

Comment: You have already asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862707) yesterday. What’s wrong with the previous one? If you want to change anything, just edit the previous question. Asking the same question again is considered dumb.